# Unable to deserialize object - Qt

Tags: c++, qt

So I serialized my object like this, and the compiler show no warning for this:

```
QDataStream out(&file);
out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_5);
out << this->board;
```

And in other function I want to deserialize it by:

```
Board *board;
QDataStream in(&file);
in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_5);
in >> board;
```

Now I cannot do that because I got warning that operator `>>` does not match that operands. Where is the problem? I followed guide on : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tutorials-addressbook-part6-example.html.

Comment: Assuming `board` is a pointer, this doesn't do what you want _at all_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of, I don't know if you've realized, but you are actually trying to read a pointer (`Board*`) from the file. You generally don't do that, since the pointer is only good as long as you don't deallocate it. Somebody might have given you this file, and where `board` was located on their computer when the generated the file is pretty useless to you.

---

Now, assuming you actually wanted to read an object (`Board`) rather than a pointer (`Board*`) :

I suppose `Board` is a class you made yourself, correct? Well, if you don't override the `operator>>`, the compiler cannot know guess to do when you ask it to read it. So you should override `operator>>`.

In the Qt page you linked to, they do not show all of the code. Look at the links at the bottom of the page, you will see [this one](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tutorials-addressbook-part6-addressbook-h.html). As you can see, `contacts` is a `QMap`, which I assume has an overridden `operator>>`. This is why they are allowed to write `in >> contacts` [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tutorials-addressbook-part6-addressbook-cpp.html).

Comment: Well only thing that was suspicious to me that the operator << for save was not causing warning, therefore I thought I can do >> with same object too. This was making my mistake. This was dumb question, I managed to do it by serializing mt object to "c_str". And then deserialize it.

Comment: @nocturne  Ah, I see.